# Show or hide a button in a J frame form using another Jframe form

Tags: java, forms, swing, jframe

Please help.
In my java project I'm taking user inputs from Jframe form "interface" and press the "check btn". Then new Jframe form "CheckEntry" popups to show whether the entered data is correct. In "CheckEntry" form there is a confirm button. When the confirm button pressed I need to **dissappear the "check btn in form Interface" and show the "save button" to send the data to the database.**

First I hide the save button in form "Interface"

```
public Interface() {
        initComponents();
        conn = db.java_db();
        Toolkit toolkit = getToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        setLocation(size.width/2 - getWidth()/2,size.height/2 - getHeight()/2);
        
        btn_save.setVisible(false);
        
    }
```

Then in "CheckEntry form", event confirm btn pressed I set the check btn to dissappear and show the save button

```
private void btn_confirm ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       
        Interface i = new Interface();

        i.btn_chk.setVisible(false);
       
        i.btn_save.setVisible(true);

        this.dispose();
      
    }
```

This is not making any change to the form Interface. Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
private void btn_confirm ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Interface i = new Interface(); // ***** HERE *****
    i.btn_chk.setVisible(false);
    i.btn_save.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
```

The problem is that while this code *does* make a JButton invisible in an Interface object, it is the *wrong* Interface object since it is one that has been newly created in this class and is not the one that is visible to the user.

A solution is to not do this, not create a new instance but to rather pass the correct visualized instance into the child window where it can be acted upon, and where its state change can be shown to the user.

So you can pass the correct instance into the child window class when you create the child window, and assign the parent window class to a variable, and then you can change it as needed.

Side note: the child window should be a JDialog, likely a modal JDialog and not another JFrame.

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainForm extends JFrame {
    private CheckEntryForm checkEntryForm = new CheckEntryForm(this);
    private JButton showCheckEntryDialogBtn = new JButton("Show Check Entry Form");
    private JButton saveEntryBtn = new JButton("Save");
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    public MainForm() {
        super("Main GUI");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        showCheckEntryDialogBtn.addActionListener(e -> {
            checkEntryForm.setVisible(true);
        });
        saveEntryBtn.setVisible(false);
        mainPanel.add(showCheckEntryDialogBtn);
        mainPanel.add(saveEntryBtn);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        add(mainPanel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MainForm().setVisible(true));
    }

    public void entryCheckOK() {
        showCheckEntryDialogBtn.setVisible(false);
        saveEntryBtn.setVisible(true);

        // let the layout managers do their thing...
        // and also remove dirty pixels
        mainPanel.revalidate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CheckEntryForm extends JDialog {
    private MainForm mainForm;
    private JButton confirmBtn = new JButton("Confirm");

    public CheckEntryForm(MainForm mainForm) {
        super(mainForm, "Check Entry", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
        confirmBtn.addActionListener(e -> confirmAction());
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(confirmBtn);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        add(mainPanel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(mainForm);
    }

    private void confirmAction() {
        mainForm.entryCheckOK();
        dispose();
    }
}
```

## Explanation

Here, the child window is a dialog window, a JDialog to be precise:

```
class CheckEntryForm extends JDialog {
```

Also, I pass a reference of the MainForm main GUI into this dialog when and where I create it:

```
private CheckEntryForm checkEntryForm = new CheckEntryForm(this);
```

and use it to set a field in the child window class:

```
class CheckEntryForm extends JDialog {
    private MainForm mainForm;
    private JButton confirmBtn = new JButton("Confirm");
    
    public CheckEntryForm(MainForm mainForm) {
        super(mainForm, "Check Entry", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.mainForm = mainForm; // **** here ***
```

Then in the child button's ActionListener, I call a public method of the main Window, one that deletes the button, and re-sets the layout managers of the container:

in child window:

```
    private void confirmAction() {
        mainForm.entryCheckOK();
        dispose();
    }
```

in the main window:

```
    public void entryCheckOK() {
        showCheckEntryDialogBtn.setVisible(false);
        saveEntryBtn.setVisible(true);
        
        // let the layout managers do their thing...
        // and also remove dirty pixels
        mainPanel.revalidate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
    }
```

---

Some side recommendations:

- Better to use a CardLayout to swap views rather than to show/hide or remove components directly.
- Better to avoid extending JFrame or JDialog directly but rather to extend or create JPanels since this will result in much more flexible code.